# How to define an Array of JSX Elements?

Tags: typescript

I have an Array that I would like to fill up with JSX Elements.

**For example:**

```
const arrayOfJsxElements : string[] = [];
    
arrayOfJsxElements.push(<div>hi</div>);
```

Unfortunately, this gives the following error (to be expected, as it isn't a string):

> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. ts(2345)

**I have tried the following (with success):**

```
import type { ReactElement } from 'react'
    
const arrayOfJsxElements : ReactElement[] = [];
    
arrayOfJsxElements.push(<div>hi</div>);
```

Now I'm looking for an easier solution instead of importing something every time I come across this problem.

What type should I use for JSX Elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer already in the TypeScript documentation:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

The correct type specification seems to be:

```
const arrayOfJsxElements : ReactElement[] = [];
```